# javascript fix json with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Hi All I want to fix my json 
I got strings without " and I need to bring them back somehow
I have found a regex that find some of the texts but still its not returning the right result

```
 var newString2 = j.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9@.,_+]*[^:][\w]/g, function(x){
      return '"'+x+'"';

    });
```

my json

```
{
  User_Story_UI_24: 
   {
     Env:Staging,
     UserName:9ascf@gmail.com,
     Password: User@SDF45sdfg,
     Supplier:Xxxxx,
     SupplierWebSite:www.xxxx.com,
     SupplierPhone:+111 2223334440,
     SupplierAddress:sss asf21, asf asf, saf
   }
}
```

the epcepted result

```
{
  "User_Story_UI_24": 
   {
     "Env":"Staging",
     "UserName":"9ascf@gmail.com",
     "Password": "User@SDF45sdfg",
     "Supplier":"Xxxxx",
     "SupplierWebSite":"www.xxxx.com",
     "SupplierPhone":"+111 2223334440",
     "SupplierAddress":"sss asf21, asf asf, saf"
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @mrzasa I think the values under `User_Story_UI_24` should be within single or double quotes, is what I understood

Comment: Where are you seeing this JSON? How is it created / sent? "Fixing a JSON" just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: One doesn't just *find* a regular expression

Comment: I can't fix the string its cam from groovy pipeline on jenkins as a parameter

Comment: if you can fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57089855/cant-send-on-groovy-sh-command it could be halpful but it seems that noone at the moment know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a regex that detects the lines in your regex (assuming it's in the same format as in your example).
Then it uses a function that receives the matching groups as its parameters and creates two quoted strings accordingly.

The only change I made to your input was adding a comma after the last property, to keep all the lines in the same format:

```js
const input = `{
  User_Story_UI_24: 
   {
     Env:Staging,
     UserName:9ascf@gmail.com,
     Password: User@SDF45sdfg,
     Supplier:Xxxxx,
     SupplierWebSite:www.xxxx.com,
     SupplierPhone:+111 2223334440,
     SupplierAddress:sss asf21, asf asf, saf,
   }
}`;

let ans = input.replace(/(\w+?): ?([+\w @.,]+),/g, (row, prop, value) => {
  return `"${prop}": "${value}",`;
});
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: ammm almost what about the User_Story_UI?

Comment: I'm afraid it has to be modified using a separate regex, as it doesn't follow the same format and therefore the replacing function will be missing a parameter. BTW the JSON is valid without properties being wrapped in quotes

Comment: need to erase the comma in the last parameter